# comparing text foreground with rectangle fill error

Tags: c#, windows-phone-8

I am developing a game of tricky colors in Windows Phone 8 
i have a text block and 8 rectangles (colors)

the mission is to press the **color of the text** and **not** the Color of the word !

example :  if the text is  :  **RED** and the Foreground of the text is **green**
the player must tap the **green** rectangle and **not** the red one

so in the checking answer function

i wrote :

```
private void CheckAnswer(Rectangle c)
        {
            if (SaveMission == 1)
            {
                if (ColorText.Foreground.Equals(c.Fill))
                    MessageBox.Show("Right Answer");
                else
                    MessageBox.Show("Wrong Answer");
            }  
        }
```

the **Foreground** property is gets `Windows.Media.Bursh`

and also **Fill** property gets `Windows.Media.Brush`

when i Debug the app : the answer is always **WRONG** !
What is the problem ?

Comment: @Sayse what do you mean by color property ?

Comment: Just debug it to see what the values are at runtime and see why they aren't equal... Or why they aren't what you think they are.

Comment: Sorry ignore that, writing from my phone and couldnt check msdn, what values are returned when you add breakpoints?

Comment: @Sayse Same ARGB value !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First an example program that will demonstrate the problem

```
System.Windows.Media.Brush b1 = new SolidColorBrush(Color.FromArgb(0,0,0,0));
System.Windows.Media.Brush b2 = new SolidColorBrush(Color.FromArgb(0, 0, 0, 0));

bool b = b1.Equals(b2);
//b will equal false
```

Now if you hover over the `.Equals` with your mouse whilst the program is not running, you will see it is using the [`DependencyObject.Equals`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa345743%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) method which "determines whether a provided DependencyObject is equivalent to the current DependencyObject." Or in other words not comparing the colors

The solution is to cast and retrieve the color

```
System.Windows.Media.Brush b1 = new SolidColorBrush(Color.FromArgb(0,0,0,0));
System.Windows.Media.Brush b2 = new SolidColorBrush(Color.FromArgb(0, 0, 0, 0));

bool b = ((SolidColorBrush)b1).Color.Equals(((SolidColorBrush)b2).Color);
```

Comment: but how i will put the bytes (ARGB) of **c** and of **ColorText** instead of zeros ?

Comment: You dont.. you just cast your `Foregrounds`

Comment: I don't follow , how to the cast the Foreground and Fill propeties ?

Comment: `((SolidColorBrush)ColorText.Foreground)`

Comment: you mean like this
`System.Windows.Media.Brush b1 = new SolidColorBrush((SolidColorBrush)ColorText.Foreground);`
?

Comment: You only need to modify the words `b1` and `b2` in the last line to include your brushes.